# What happened to the macros API in Scala 2.11?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-2.11

I am trying to port a macro from Scala 2.10 to 2.11.0-M7:

```
import scala.reflect.macros.Context

object Format {
  def apply[A]: Unit = macro applyImpl[A]

  def applyImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): c.Expr[Unit] = ???
}
```

Something must have changed, because the compiler says `scala.reflect.macros.Context` doesn't exist.

My build file looks like this:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.0-M7"

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")

addCompilerPlugin("org.scala-lang.plugins" % "macro-paradise" % "2.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  cross CrossVersion.full)
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One needs to explicitly add `scala-reflect` now:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value
```

`Context` is deprecated, but it compiles.

Comment: I think it was always necessary to explicitly depend on scala-reflect.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako - actually, no, my library was compiling [without explicit reflect](https://github.com/Sciss/play-json-sealed/blob/master/project/Build.scala) in 2.10; anyway no big issue, it works now :)